# is there a TSLint rule to force a newline after a function declaration

Tags: tslint

For some reason, some members of our team started skipping newline characters following method declaration, like this:

```
function one(){
// some code
}
function two(){
// some code
}
```

**Is there a TSLint rule I can use to force them to use 1 newline between declarations**? like this:

```
function one(){
//some code
}

function two(){
// some code
}
```